# ImportError:python2.7/dist-packages/RPIO-2.0: undefined symbol: makedev

Tags: pi-3b+, opencv, python-2.x, rpio

I have a problem with RPIO. I am running a face recognition using OpenCV python on Raspberry Pi 3B+.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/facerec-pi/code $ sudo python capture-positives.py
     Tradeback (most recent call last):
            File "capture-positives.py", line 14, in <module>
                 import hardware
            File "/home/pi/facerec-pi/code/hardware.py", line 9, in <module>
               from RPIO import PWM
           File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/RPIO/PWM/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
           File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/RPIO/PWM/_PWM.py", line 7, in <module>
           File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/RPIO/PWM/_PWM.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
           ImportError: /root/.cache/Python-Eggs/RPIO-2.0.0b1-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg-tmp/RPIO/PWM/_PWM.so: undefined symbol: makedev
```

This is what the terminal return after I run the program. I am using the RPOP V2 updated for Pi2, Pi3.

Comment: Are you sure RPIO was built successfully?  What happens if you use it with a very simple script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem using branch v2 of this RPIO fork (https://github.com/JamesGKent/RPIO/tree/v2) on a Pi Zero W. 
RPIO builds successfully and the error occurs already when importing PWM from RPIO.

Solution: Include sys/sysmacros.h in file source/c_pwm/mailbox.c was missing.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my problem. Do you have any problem using the RPIO afterward?

Comment: Until now, RPIO is working like expected.